# Python Flask | Display post comment

Tags: python, flask

How do i display post comment when i click on the "comment" link?

I just want to show one post from the user, but it only displays the username.

## Models.py

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ["body"]

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

def __repr__(self):
    return self.body
```

## Views.py

```
@app.route("/comment/<username>")
@app.route("/comment/<username>/<int:page>") 
@login_required
def comment(username, page=1):
    form = CommentForm()
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()  
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('comment'))
    posts = user.followed_posts().paginate(page, POSTS_PER_PAGE, False)
    return render_template("comment.html", form=form, username=username, user=user, posts=posts)
```

## Comment.html

```
{{ username }}
{{ body }} 
<form action="" method="POST"> 
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }} 
    {{ form.comment(size=auto) }}
    <button class="send-comment"> Kirim </button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see that you have "returned" the variable "body" to jinja2 when rendering comment.html.

Maybe you should change `{{ body }}` to `{{ posts }}` in your "comment.html" file?

Comment: oh yeah, i mean here want to adding single post comment like a facebook
when i add {{ post.body }}
so i get all post from user cause looping, so i want to show post that i will give comment